# Metadata API deployments are failing in Spring '19

Tags: metadata-api, spring19

For some time now (several years) I've been deploying changes to Apex classes using the Metadata API [deploy web method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm) with an associated zip file containing the metadata and package.xml file.

This morning when I tried to deploy to na87 on Spring 19 with patch 11.5 it failed with the message:

> 1. : package.xml (classes/package.xml) (line:0 column:0)
>      No package.xml found

I double checked the zip file I was sending in. It had the structure:

- classes/TheApexClassToDeploy.cls
- classes/TheApexClassToDeploy.cls-meta.xml
- package.xml

The package.xml had:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>TheApexClassToDeploy</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

It isn't clear to me why this package format isn't correct anymore. Did I miss something in the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_api_meta.htm)?

Based on the error message I took a punt and created this package.xml file in the classes folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

Which seemed to allow the deploy to proceed.

I'll go down the path of raising a support case for this, but I'd be interested to know if I've missed a documented change to the Metadata API format.

---

Verification in Workbench migration/deploy using v45.0:

[image]

If I change the root level package.xml from:

`<version>45.0</version>`

to:

`<version>44.0</version>`

The deploy works against the v45.0 Metadata API endpoint.

---

As suggested by [Pranay](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252340/metadata-api-deployments-are-failing-in-spring-19?noredirect=1#comment383370_252340) I did a retrieve via Workbench using v45.0 with the package.xml file and "Single Package" checked.

[image]

It doesn't appear to have the additional package.xml file.

I then did a Metadata deploy with the resulting zip file. It failed in the same way as it did above. I then tired again, but checked "Single Package"... and it deployed.

Maybe they are enforcing something new around the `singlePackage` setting?

Comment: Can you try removing  `standalone="true"` , in package.xml ?

Comment: According to docs, standalone can have only 2 possible values, yes and no. Making it true might make XML invalid and give you errors.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256048(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Good catch. I checked my actual package.xml file and it has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>`. I'm not sure I ended up with `=true` in my example.

Comment: Can you provide the same `package.xml` in retrevie command and see whats the file structure of retreived zip ?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Added details to the Q. I could do a retrieve and get the same package.zip file back - *if I checked single package*. If I didn't I got an extra "unpackaged" folder in the root of the zip. I think this may be the root of the problem. I could deploy my new retrieved zip file only if I also checked singlePackage. Maybe they are enforcing something that they didn't previously around that setting.

Comment: Might be something to do with unlocked packages with second generation packaging. 2 packages can include same class

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Do you want to post an answer for this. Essentially "singlePackage" needs to be used for v45.0 when it is indeed a single package. With v44.0 there was some leniency based on the actual contents of the zip file.

Comment: You found solution. I believe you should be the one answering :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per the discussion with Pranay in the comments, the cause of the issue was the "singlePackage" setting in the [deploy options](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm#deployOptions).

> Indicates whether the specified .zip file points to a directory structure with a single package (true) or a set of packages (false).

Typically my deployment tooling would have this set to true (and then would work fine with v45.0), but somehow I'd managed to set it to false.

With "singlePackage" set to `false` but a package zip file for a single package against v44.0 the deploy would still be successful. My assumption here is that Salesforce was examining the actual contents of the zip file and adjusting the settings accordingly.

With v45.0 that no longer appears to be the case. `singlePackage` must be set to `true` when deploying a single package. Otherwise it will fail while looking for the expected package.xml files for the inner packages.

Oddly, it will still work with v45.0 if the inner package.xml files are empty and the root package.xml was valid for the single package.

So what did we (re)learn?
**Use the `singlePackage` setting correctly when deploying a single package!**